# AsyncTask in Fragments to perform Database update

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have over 10 `fragments` that execute the same kind of task which is :

1. Retrieving the Data from the server using `Retrofit`
2. Starting an Async Task to update the Database (Using ORMLite)
3. Once the Database is updated, retrieving the new data from the Database
4. Notify Dataset has changed in the adapter

I'm wondering if it's useless to put the update database code inside an `AsyncTask` within my fragment once I retrieve the data from the server?
I have trouble understanding what run on the UI thread and what doesn't and should be started as his own thread through an `AsyncTask`

Here my code:

```
private void getLocalIncidentTemplate() {
    mIncidentTemplate.clear();
    mIncidentTemplate.addAll(GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityGroup.class).queryForAll());
    Collections.sort(mIncidentTemplate);
    Log.e(TAG, "Incident Template count:" + mIncidentTemplate.size());
    mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void getRemoteIncidentTemplate() {
    Call<EntityIncident> call = meepServices.getIncidentTemplate();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<EntityIncident>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EntityIncident> call, Response<EntityIncident> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                new updateIncidentTemplateTask().execute(response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EntityIncident> call, Throwable t) {
            t.getStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            Utils.showToastMessage(getActivity(), "Error retrieving Incidents", true);
        }

    });
}

private class updateIncidentTemplateTask extends AsyncTask<EntityCategories, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(EntityCategories... params) {
        updateIncidents(params[0]);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
        getLocalIncidentTemplate();
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**Here is the Database Update Using ORMlite:**

```
private void updateIncident(EntityCategories categories) {

    try {
        categories.setId("MobilePlan");
        //Update base categories
        GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityCategories.class).addOrUpdate(categories);

        for (EntityCategories.EntityCategory currentCategory : new ArrayList<>(categories.getCategories())) {

            if (currentCategory.getmPlans() != null) {
                for (EntityPlan myPlan : new ArrayList<>(currentCategory.getmPlans())) {
                    EntityPlan oldPlan = GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityPlan.class).queryById(String.valueOf(myPlan.getmId()));
                    myPlan.setCategories(currentCategory);
                    if (oldPlan != null) {
                        if (!myPlan.getmDateModification().equals(oldPlan.getmDateModification())) {
                            GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityPlan.class).addOrUpdate(myPlan);
                        }
                    } else {
                        GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityPlan.class).addOrUpdate(myPlan);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                continue;
            }

            GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityLabel.class).addOrUpdate(currentCategory.getmLabel());
            currentCategory.setCategories(categories);
            GenericDAO.getInstance(EntityCategories.EntityCategory.class).addOrUpdate(currentCategory);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "DATA updated");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case, you should use the `AsyncTask` to retrieve data from the backend and place it in the database.
Remember that `AsyncTask` has three main methods:

- `onPreExecute()` that runs on the UI thread. Useful when you need to prep something that requires UI thread (touching views and whatnot)
- `doInBackGround()` this runs on background thread
- `onPostExecute()` runs also on the UI thread.

In `onPostExecute()` you could notify your adapter of the new data.

If I were you, I'd use loaders to get notified and retrieve the data off the database. So that the complete chain would be some:

1. `AsyncTask` pulls data from the backend and stores it in the database
2. Your loader will get notified that something changed inside the database and will pull the data from it and call `onLoadFinished()` method inside your activity/fragment
3. `onLoadFinished()` passes the data to the view adapter.

I haven't gone into detail as to how to implement this. I just presented the overall architecture.

Comment: But retrofit library is already async for the Data Retriving from the server. And when I store the data in the Database, I use ORMLite. I'm not sure if that one is async.

Comment: Retrofit has both synchronous and asynchronous calls. I personally normally implement my own background thread (via `IntentService`, `GcmTaskService` or any other) that then calls the synchronous API of Retrofit and also stores the data into the database. Then loaders on my activity/fragments to populate the view from the app data model.

Comment: What do you mean by Loaders on your Activity/Fragment? How you I pass the Data from the IntentService back to the Activity/Fragment? Also, do you have a custom implementation of the IntentService for each type of operation or is it generic?

Comment: (1) Loaders: Take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html). Loaders is one of the patterns provided by the Android framework to load data from you app data model (e.g. database) into activity/fragment. You'll find plenty of tutorial/resources in google. (2) Whether I use one or several worker threads depends very much on the nature of the network cals. Normally one per type of data to fetch and the specifics of the query can be configured using via `intent` extras, arguments and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks, That's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

> I have trouble understanding what run on the UI thread and what doesn't and should be started as his own thread

### The short answer:

Everything that might block the UI thread (in other words, might take time) should run on a worker thread (threadpool or dedicated)
DB actions and network requests are classic examples for actions that should always run asynchronously.

In your case I would just use an ORM to wrap all the interaction with the DB, such as [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) or any other you find more suitable, in that case you will not have to concern yourself with the inner workings and just provide callbacks for when your calls have finished (successfully or not)

Comment: Okay, it's starting to be more clear, but I noticed I my question was not well asked. I'm actually using ORMLite to perform database update (I added the code to the method **updateIncidents**). So basically I put the ORMLite code inside a AsyncTask. Does that means I put an already async code inside an AsyncTask?

Comment: Also, Should I keep the ORMlite update method in the fragment or put them in a separate class for the **single responsibility principe**?

Comment: OK, got it now. My answer is then a bit off the mark. The raw method calls are indeed blocking so what  you are doing by placing them in the `doInBackground()` is correct and as you said should be extracted to a `wrapper` that will allow basic CRUD operations to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: So ORMLite operation are blocking then? Do you have a good example of wrapper architecture to wrap the CRUD database operation?